# Why do I get an 0xCCCCCCCC error after allocating memory for the strings in my struck?

Tags: c, dynamic

When running my program, you can find the code below, that holds a dynamically allocated array with structs, I run into a problem.

Steps to reproduce the bug:

- Run the program
- Enter 'a' as input so that the program will add the first person to the array
- Enter 'a' again as input so that you will add the second person to the array
- allocate the memory for the dynamic string of the name of the second person (`database[*n]->name = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);` in `newPerson()` funcion)

I get the following error:

> Exception thrown at 0x013D1C48 in IPHoofdstuk13_13.2.6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

It's really weird since that particular code does its job when I add the first guy to the list, but when I want to add another guy I get the error mentioned above.

I've been trying to solve this for hours now, is there someone who knows how and mostly why this error occured?

The code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MAP
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 81

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct person
{
     char* name;
     char* adres;
}person;

/*Function prototypes*/
void newPerson(person **database, int *n);
void printDatabase(const person *database, int n);
void freeDatabase(person **database, int n);
void bufferCheck(char string[]);


int main(void)
{
    person *database = NULL;//Array Pointer
    int npersonen = 0;
    bool stop = false;

    while (!stop)
    {
        char c;

        printf("Press a to add a new person\n");
        printf("Press p to print all the persons\n");
        printf("press q to quit the program\n");
        c = _getche();

        switch (c)
        {
        case 'a':
            newPerson(&database, &npersonen);
            break;

        case 'p':
            printDatabase(database, npersonen);
            break;

        case 'q':
            stop = true;
            break;

        default:
            printf("Wrong input ... \n");
            break;
        }
    }

    freeDatabase(&database, npersonen);

    free(database);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}

void newPerson(person **database, int *n)
{
    /* Create new array */
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    //Create space for n + 1 persons
    person *old = realloc(*database, (*n + 1) * sizeof(*old));

    if (old == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory reallocation failed...\n");
    }

    *database = old;//use larger array

    /* Get name */
    printf("\nEnter name: ");
    fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    bufferCheck(buffer);


    database[*n]->name = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);

    if ((database)[*n]->name == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed...\n");
    }

    strcpy((*database)[*n].name, buffer);

    /* Get Adress */
    printf("\nEnter adress: ");
    fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    bufferCheck(buffer);

    database[*n]->adres = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);

    if ((database)[*n]->adres == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed...\n");
    }

    strcpy((*database)[*n].adres, buffer);

    /* Free old array */
    free(old);

    /* Increase array length */
    ++(*n);
}

void printDatabase(const person *database, int n)
{
    if (n < 1)
        printf("List is empty\n");

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            printf("\nPerson %d: \n", i + 1);
            printf("\t Name: %s", database[i].name);
            printf("\t Adres: %s", database[i].adres);
        }
    }
}

void freeDatabase(person **database, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        free(database[i]->name);
        free(database[i]->adres);
    }
}

void bufferCheck(char string[])
{
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (string[i] == '\n')
            string[i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: `(*database)[*n].name` instead of `database[*n]->name` in `newPerson()` (and elsewhere, when passed in as `person **`)

Comment: and `free(old);`  is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of `person` allocated, accessible from `main()` through a `person *` to the first struct in the array.  You're passing it to other functions as a `person **` to allow for changing the address of the array, which is fine... but then you're attempting to access elements of the array without dereferencing properly.

In the functions where you have passed `person **database`, you need to access the structs of the array by first dereferencing `database` to get the actual pointer value (the address the variable in main holds), then index that pointer to get at the struct you want -- so you need `(*database)[*n]` to get the `person` struct, rather than trying to use `database[*n]` to get a pointer to it (which won't work, because the pointer you're indexing is pointing to the pointer in `main()` and not to the array you allocated).

So, for example, in `newPerson()`, the line:

```
database[*n]->name = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
```

...would become:

```
(*database)[*n].name = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
```

...and other occurrences would change similarly.

---

And as @BLUEPIXY commented, don't free `old` after `realloc()`ing the array, since you're still using the block it points to.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what I did wrong and what I should change. The function works fine now. With your explanation I was also able to debug my free funtion for those dynamic strings within 2 seconds. The program works now, thank you!

Comment: Your `freeDatabase` will change as well, e.g. `free ((*database)[i].name);`

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
database[*n]->name = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
```

does not seem right. It should be:

```
old[*n]->name = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);
```

Comment: Hey @RSahu your solution worked as well, thank you very much!